# Can I use two forms in a single page with runat="server"?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a login form, and a link that when you press it, the login form becomes a register form using innerHTML. The problem is, that the page won't let me use two forms with runat="server".

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one
>   server-side Form tag.

My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = '<h1>Register:</h1><br>';
str += '<form id="reg" method="post" action="Mainlogin.aspx" runat="server">';
```

...

```
function register()
    {
        document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = str;
    }
</script> 

<div id="here">

<form id="form1" method="post" action="Mainlogin.aspx" runat="server">
<h1>Please Login:</h1>
</p> <br />
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

...

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Adding a form with Javacript, the server is not going to see it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can have only one runat=server form on the page.  if you want, rather than change the form, you could add a hidden field on the page and update that with say 0 or 1 to indicate which option the user picked.

Comment: When the user clicks the link to change the form type, update the hidden field with the value you want to represent that form type, rather than changing the form.  when they submit the form you can pick up that hidden field value and use that to determine which form type was submitted.

Comment: Thanks for thee answer, but how can I change the text from Login to Register?
Do you mean `<input type="hidden>`? If so, should I be able to create two <div>s and just change the "Hidden" Property?
`<div hidden="Hidden">Register</div>`   `<div>Login</div>`

Comment: you could either do it through a postback, setup a click event on the link.  otherwise if you want to do it clientside, without a postback, just do as you said setup two divs and hide and show them, jquery if you have used it has a way to hide/show html elements.